# is it possible to define custom attribute for an activity tag in an android manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible  to define custom  attribute for an `activity` tag in an Android manifest file ?

```
<activity xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.dateviewdemo"
    android:name=".main.RegistrationActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
    custom:show="false"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Android gives feature for Android widget.

Comment: Why do your need such feature? What do you want to do?

Comment: Please follow http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr  but I have tried it with custom view not sure it can be achieved with activity or pre-defined views

Comment: i just want to such curiosity about activity tag , i think we also customize activity through xml

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any solution for custom attributes for `<activity>`, but a workaround by `<meta-data>`:

```java
    public static String getMetaDataValue(Activity activity, String name) {
        try {
            ActivityInfo activityInfo = activity.getPackageManager()
                    .getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle bundle = activityInfo.metaData;
            if (bundle == null) return null;
            return bundle.getString(name);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```xml
<activity>
<meta-data android:name="key" android:value="value"/>
</activity>
```